# Joomla3 - Warning You cannot access the private section of this site

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

My joomla is 3.3.6. Just installed. All php configuration are as it's required.
I have create a new Group at backend:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s396/sh/ ... 2973ff37f1

After i did that, i turned the "New User Registration Group" at Users Configuration (tab component) to my new Group "Volunteer":
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s396/sh/ ... 0843e0d80b

Then, in Frontend i registered a new user as usual with the register form. Here you can see is saved at backend as a user in the Volunteer Group: [dont have 10 point of rep] imagin the picture

Now i go to my login in my frontend, i do the login with my user and pass and i got this:
[dont have 10 point of rep] imagin the picture

Does anyone know why the system is throwing me this Warning:

??? I really appreciate the help.
Thnaks All

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla! administration, not programming. You might get help on [joomla.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 0):

It means the page that it redirects to after logging in is for "Registered" users (users in the Registered user group), not Volunteers.